# To print the content of a file (supporting extensions like r,tex,txt,rnw) using R?

Tags: file, r, printing

Is it possible to print the content of a file (supporting extensions like r,tex,txt,rnw) using R?

Reproducible file:

```
sink('myFile')
cat('\nThis is some text')
cat('\n')
cat('\nEnd of file')
sink()
```

Now I am looking for a function in R that prints the content of R as...

```
>PRINT_FILE_CONTENT('myFile')
This is some text
End of file
>
```

I hope I am clear. I will appreciate any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
cat(readLines("myFile"),sep="\n")
```

although I did get

```
Warning message:
In readLines("myFile") : incomplete final line found on 'myFile'
```

at the end ... you could wrap it in `suppressWarnings()` if you like.